# Missing nested exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

I'm doing some testing of my stateless session beans from a junit class so the flow goes something like this.

Junit test method calls a business method in bean A. This method throws a CustomException.

Bean A business method calls bean B business method. This method also throws a CustomException.

Bean B calls a remote Bean C which throws a BeanCException. Bean B catches an AccountBadFormatException, wraps it in CustomException and throws is back to Bean A.

From Bean A CustomException is rethrown back to JUnit calling code. When I catch CustomException in JUnit and look at it, there is no AccountBadFormatException inside. The cause reads "CustomException" and the stacktrace is gone. But If I look at it in Bean A just before it gets thrown to JUnit the nested exception is there. Why would this happen?

JUnit class:

```
@Test
public void testGetResult() {

    setupContext();

    Result result = null;
    try {
        result = (Result) serviceInterface.getResult("000001", "01011970");
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        System.out.println("CustomException getCause() in JUnit: " + e.getCause().toString());
        fail();
    }

    assertTrue((result.getReturnCode() == ReturnCode.OK));
}
```

Bean A:

```
   @Override
public Result getResult(String clientID, String dob) throws CustomException {

    Result result = new Result(ReturnCode.ERROR);
    boolean isMatched = false;
    try {
        isMatched = Lookup.getUtilityService().isIdentMatched(clientID, dob);
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        System.out.println("CustomException getCause() in Bean A: " + e.getCause().toString());
        throw e;
    }

    if (isMatched) {
        result.setReturnCode(ReturnCode.OK);
    }

    return result;

}
```

Bean B:

```
    @Override
public boolean isIdentMatched(String clientID, String dob) throws CustomException {



    IdentRequest request = new IdentRequest(clientID);
    ClientSummary response = null;
    // retrieve the data
    try {
        response = getRetriever().getClientSummaryView(request)
                .getClientSummary();
    } catch (XrefAccountNumberException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (AccountNotFoundException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (AccountBadFormatException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (ExclusiveLockException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return response.isMismatch();
}
```

The output of the print statement in Bean A is: "CustomException getCause() in Bean A: ca.gc.cra.iica.iasi.common.exceptions.AccountBadFormatException"

The print statement in JUnit is: "CustomException getCause() in JUnit: ca.gc.cra.fltr.filemyreturn.business.exceptions.CustomException"

Comment: [MCVE] please. Thank you.

Comment: Show us some code. How is the exception wrapping code setup?

Comment: @yogidilip added code.

Comment: @Tom added code.